# C# Sum of values from txt file

Tags: c#

How do I take the sum of the values from "Values.txt"? And how do I display it? I am very new to coding, this is for an entry level coding course.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader("Values.txt");
    string line = "";

    while (line != null)
    {
        line = myReader.ReadLine();
        if (line != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the contents of values.txt look like, please? is there one number per line, perhaps? Are the values integers (whole numbers) or decimals? The detail of the file format and data types will affect the solution

Comment: I hope in your Values.txt contains multiple lines and each line has only 1 string that is number?

Comment: @Ziggler I didn't downvote, but the fact the OP is on an entry-level course doesn't prevent the question from being "unclear", or "not useful" (as per the downvote reasons you see when you hover over the button). The question is arguably unclear, because crucial information is missing - i.e. the data format, and I'm not sure that being a coding beginner is an excuse for that - if this was an exercise to be done on paper instead of code, we would still need to know what the input values looked like. So it's a logical omission, regardless of your experience level.

Comment: Consider it an introduction to what will become a mantra for the rest of his coding life; manager comes in gushing about a half baked harebrained idea he dreamt up while on the John and wants implementing yesterday and the developer says .... "have you got a spec for that?" :)

Comment: I played my part in showing him right direction considering OP's honesty. That's enough for me. Question clearly made sense to me and want to give him helping hand.

Comment: Sorry, I could've made the txt file more clear. But I listed the txt file and then summed it all together. Thank you everyone for the help! @Ziggler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my attempt on a single line of code.

ReadAllLines will read all the lines into an Array of strings.
You can use the built in method .Sum() on an array to add up all the numbers, but since the array is made up of strings, we can convert the string to integer by using int.Parse().

[Definition of ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllLines_System_String_)

[Definition of Array.Sum()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8)

Now since we know how to read up all the lines from a file and convert them to numbers, we can use the statement `Sum(x => int.Parse(x))` .. which means, parse the string to number and sum them all up.

```
int sum = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\numbers.txt").Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
// sum = 29
```

the numbers.txt file has content:

```
10
10
2
2
2
3
```

**Process in Detail:**

- `File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)` generates Array of strings. We can run various processes on the array, like Sum, Count, Average, etc.
- `(x => int.Parse(x))` itself generates an array of numbers based on `each line` (represented by x) in the string array. If we can get the number array, we can use the method of Sum(arrayOfNumbers)
- `Array.Sum(x => int.Parse(x))` generates single number which is a sum of all numbers of Array.

Comment: You forgot to output it.. but do note; this isn't codegolf and the OP has just started out in programming; while interesting, this answer is likely to be near incomprehensible and unusable to a beginner

Comment: I used this code to sum the numbers, thank you for the help! @Jawad

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume the text file only contains integers, one per line. I'm not using LINQ for this because you're just starting out and it would be better to get a grounding in normal loops and parsing first. This way is also intolerant of bad data:

```
//read all the file into an array, one line per array entry
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\values.txt");

//declare a variable to hold the sum
int sum = 0;

//go through the lines one by one...
foreach(string line in lines)
  //...converting the line to a number and then adding it to the sum
  sum = sum + int.Parse(line);

//print the result
Console.WriteLine("sum is " + sum);
```

And for compare with how we might write these days with LINQ and other code shortenings:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\values.txt");
var sum = lines.Sum(e => int.TryParse(e, out int x) ? x : 0);
Console.WriteLine($"sum is {sum}");
```

This latter form uses TryParse to tolerate bad data. Don't hand this code in as your homework- your supervisor will know for sure someone else wrote it; the inline conditional, LINQ, string interpolation, shorthand oarsing output variable and var declarations etc are all things that you wouldn't cover in a programming 101, it's purely for reference and your own curiosity :)

Answer (score 3):

You've got the barebones of reading each line from the file, so what you need to do now is *parse* the lines as integers. Assuming that each line is *solely* a number, you can do the following:

What you would do is declare a variable, an integer (you can change this) that stores the sum, starting from 0. Then, inside the null check if block, you can put the following:

```
// Check whether the line is an integer.
if (Int32.TryParse(line, out int parseValue) {
    // Add the value to the sum.
    sum += parseValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to read file and get all lines. Then loop each line and check whether it is number or not and then add.

```
 string[] strNumbers = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyFolder\Values.txt");
 int count = 0;
 foreach (string strNumber in strNumbers)
 {
   if (Int32.TryParse(strNumber, out int number)) 
   {
      count = count + number;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine("Total : " +count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = File.ReadLines("Values.txt")
    .Select(line => Convert.ToInt32(line))
    .Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: Why select, why not do a sum directly?

Comment: so `lines.Sum(Convert.ToInt32)`? Yeah thats nicer :)

Comment: Also if you use `Rile.ReadLines` instead it will read each line one by one while doing the parsing and summing instead of reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: Yeah switching to ReadLines. Went back to the old version with the `Select` though. It feels more readable.